# Problem Refreshing 4-digit 7-segment display with UART on the MSP430G2553

Tags: uart, msp430, 7segmentdisplay

I'm working on a program that:

- samples the ADC every half a second with timer interrupt
- sends a signal via UART on button press (port 2 interrupt)
- displays the ADC value to a 4-digit multiplexed 7-segment display refreshed at 100 Hz using timer interrupt

The problem I have is that the 7-segment seems to be muddling up the UART signal.  Here is the portion of code that sends the integer to the 7-segment to be displayed.  It seems to be causing the problems.

```
void shiftOut(short val)
{
    //Set latch to low (should be already)
    P2OUT &= ~LATCH;

    int i;

    // Iterate over each bit, set data pin, and pulse the clock to send it
    // to the shift register
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if ((val & (1 << i))){
            P2OUT |= DATA;
        } else {
            P2OUT &= ~DATA;
        }
        P2OUT |= CLOCK;
        P2OUT ^= CLOCK;
    }

    // Pulse the latch pin to write the values into the storage register
    P2OUT |= LATCH;
    P2OUT &= ~LATCH;
}
```

If I slow down the 7-segment refresh rate, the UART signal is fine, but the 7-segment flickers.  I'm not quite sure why the UART signal is getting messed up, so if someone can point out the errors that I've made, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: How is the seven segment flickering if the data is latched? That shouldn't really be possible...

Comment: I guess, You have messed up with your port configuration.Because once the 7-segment is latched it should not flicker. Why you are refreshing the 7-segment display. From my experience I know that 7-segment doesnt require refreshing. It only requires refresh when you want to change the content.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but there are no delays between setting and clearing the shift and latch clocks. And you use two mechanisms for clearing: & and ^.

Comment: I'm actually calling the above function with an interrupt at 100 Hz.  This function is also called by another function which determines which digit to write to.  I am displaying a constantly changing ADC value, so I need to refresh it.  Also, I'm multiplexing the 7-seg displays (4 digits), so I need to refresh them fast enough so the flickering isn't noticeable.  

I thought it was the port initialization as well, but the problem work if the interrupt is working at lower frequencies.  But at lower frequencies, the flickering is much more pronounced.